How to infer generic function with type parameter using `infer`
TypeScript can automatically generate a generic function if one of the parameters is a type parameter from another generic function, without having to explicitly define it as a generic.
export function fn<P, R>(cb: (param: P) => R) {
  // No explicit generic definition
  return (param: P, extra?: unknown) => {
    console.log(extra)
    return cb(param)
  }
}

// `f` is inferred as generic -- const f: <S>(param: S, extra?: unknown) => S
const f = fn(<S>(str: S) => str)
const returned = f("value") // typeof returned is `"value"`

However, I could not get this to work with ordinary types using the infer keyword
export type Fn<T extends (param: never) => unknown> = T extends (
  param: infer P
) => infer R
  ? (param: P) => R
  : never

// type F = `(param: unknown) => unknown` instead of `<V>(v: V) => V`
type F = Fn<<V>(v: V) => V>

Is there something I'm missing?
Also, extending from above concerning fn, I noticed that TS doesn't infer a generic anymore if the function is overloaded, which is where my actual use case lies.
export function fn<P, R>(cb: { (): ""; (param: P): R }) {
  // No explicit generic definition
  return (param: P, extra?: unknown) => {
    console.log(extra)
    return cb(param)
  }
}

// typeof f is not generic if function is overloaded
// const f: (param: { value: unknown; }, extra?: unknown) => unknown
const f = fn({} as unknown as { (): ""; <S>(str: S): S })
const returned = f({ value: "value" as const }) // typeof returned is `unknown`


Is there a way to make it work?

No, you cannot make this work. TypeScript's support for higher order generic function inference is limited to what's implemented in ms/TS#30215. It doesn't work with conditional types (the infer bit) or overloads. It's fragile. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz Thanks. That fully addresses the question.

Try modifying your type like this:
export type Fn<T> = T extends <P>(
  param: P
) => P
  ? <P>(param: P) => P
  : never;

type F = Fn<<V>(v: V) => V>; 

This will infer the correct type for F.
const test: F = <T, >(param: T) => param;

const res = test('val') // type for res will be 'val'
const res = test({ val: 1 }) // type will be { val: number }


So it only works when the generic function is exactly of the from <T>(param: T) => T? And then it returns the same type? Presumably the point of Fn<T> is to work on all generic functions, not the specific one in the example.
